# WiX installer Bundle Launch App after install

Tags: wix, bundle, wix3.8

I have one bundle that includes PackageGroupRef for NetFx45Web, one ExePackage for needed driver and  MsiPackage for my app.
I want to launch my app after whole installation process completes.
I tried using

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#myEXE]" />
    <CustomAction Id='LaunchFile'
        BinaryKey="WixCA"
        DllEntry="WixShellExec"
        Impersonate="yes"/>
```

in my app MsiPackage but it starts the app before installation is complete(when MsiPackage completes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a variable like this, in your `bundle.wxs`:

```
<Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\YourFolder\YourExe.exe"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way to solve the launching. And it is the current one for my project. Disadvantage is that new button.
If there is a way to have it with a check box like in the regular case it would be perfect.